# Add timestamp column to panel in Grafana

Tags: timestamp, grafana, datasource, infinity, grafana-alerts

I’m using the Infinity data source to get my servers status, and currently I’m using the table format in the panel. In order to be able to set up alerting on it, it needs to be a time series, but I cannot change it because I don`t have in the response the timestamp. I was wondering if there is any way it can be added either from the data or external (local time).
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Current output:

| health | name | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ok | server1 | running |

Expected output:

| health | name | state | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ok | server1 | running | "sysdate" |

Thank you

Comment: Hi Kelso, you can use Grafana Transformations to add a timestamp to the data displayed in your panel.